# Зачем удалять событие после выполнения этого события?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Изучаю код простого слайдера. (Для повышения скила учусь читать чужой код)
https://github.com/earaujoassis/vanilla-slider/

Роясь в исходниках обнаружил каким образом разработчик навешивает события с помощью `addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fun(){...},false`), чтобы запустить слайдер после того как dom готов к работе.
Тут вроде все логично, но не могу понять зачем он это же событие удаляет после исполнения callback'a? (таким образом):

```
d.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", evnt, false);
```

Ниже ссылка на это самое место (думаю с контекстом будет понятнее)
https://github.com/earaujoassis/vanilla-slider/blob/master/src/vanilla-slider.js#L106

Вопрос больше идеологический, зачем это вообще могут делать?
Спасибо.

Comment: чтобы на документе больше не весел этот обработчик

Comment: @Grundy , ок, а практическая польза? Может есть линк на исчерпывающий манул?

Comment: на документе меньше обработчиков. Вполне себе практическая польза

Comment: _манул_ по чему? Как работают события в JS?

Comment: @Grundy, если в контексте мануала поясняется зачем это делать и какова польза, то можно и на неё (сарказм в сторону). За направление спасибо, перечитаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исторически так сложилось, что удалять ненужные более обработчики считается хорошей практикой. В частности древние IE не умели корректно работать с обработчиками, и если вы удаляли dom-элемент с обработчиком, и не удаляли сначала этот обработчик, из за циклических ссылок друг на друга у dom-элемента и обработчика они оставались в памяти, что приводило к утечке

Comment: Небольшое замечание. Второй способ разорвать циклическую ссылку - удалять или обnullять переменные после того как они перестанут быть нужны.